# Is there anything that might not work on office excel 2007 compare to office excel 2016?

Tags: excel, vba

Our company is planning to upgrade Office 2007 to Office 2016. We have worksheets that uses macros. Is it going to be an issues that anyone know of when they have transition from earlier version to Office 2016?

Comment: Office 2010 vs Office 2007 would be already a significant jump: http://www.excel-ticker.com/the-most-important-changes-to-vba-in-excel-2010/ But from 2007 over to 2016 is an even greater jump. I'd be surprised if all of your macros would work without any alterations.

Comment: The very least you need to check is late and early binding. You will likely have to update some macros, but it is totally worth it, O2007 is a pile of rubbish, while O2016 actually works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Googling "ms office vba compatibility 2007 2010 2016" yields some helpful results:

- M$ has some telemetry information published in [Compatibility issues in Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj229903.aspx). It's primarily UI controls and components that are dropped from later versions
- At M$ forums, [someone asking the same question is being pointed](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/0b41209f-3964-4d9c-ad4a-ca7a6398d1f4/the-differences-between-vba-of-office-2007-and-vba-of-2010?forum=excel) to [the same link that @Ralph gave](http://www.excel-ticker.com/the-most-important-changes-to-vba-in-excel-2010/)
- Users mention issues with API calls in [VBA compatibility issues: Excel 2007, 2010, 2013](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/971741-vba-compatibility-issues-excel-2007-2010-2013-a.html) (although that's not the OP's problem apparently)

If you're upgrading your business environment, you'll be testing it out anyway prior to mass deployment - at least, all the common use cases.